# How do I use excel vba to interact with Bloomberg terminal?

Tags: excel, bloomberg, dde

Looks like Bloomberg doesn’t support DDE any longer.

So how can I achieve this same outcome with excel VBA now?

```
Blp = DDEInitiate("Winblp", "bbk")
Call DDEExecute(Blp, "<Blp-1>" & "AAPL US <EQUITY>" & " DES<GO>")
Call DDETerminate(Blp)
```